# How to execute alarm on Android 10?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to ring alarm on exact time but below code is not working on Android 10.

If app is in stack alarm ring successfully but when its not in recent app stack it never run on any os version.

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        manager.setAlarmClock(
                new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(
                        timeMillis,
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0)
                ),
                getIntent(context)
        );
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, getIntent(context));
        else
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, getIntent(context));

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
        intent.putExtra("alarmSet", true);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

I have added below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.learntodroid.simplealarmclock.permission.ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

What can i do to ring alarm on Android 10?

Answer (score 1):

To schedule an alarm at a specific time try this:

First Schedule an alarm at your desired time using Alarm Manager

```
void scheduleAlarm(Context context) {

        // scheduling an alarm at 05:00 PM

        //getting instance of a calendar
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //setting exact date and time of alarm
        // in my case it is 17/11/2020 at 05.00 PM
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,10); // month count starts from 0; here 10 denotes November
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2020); // year
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,17); // day
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17); // hour
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0); // min

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,12345678,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        android.app.AlarmManager alarmManager = (android.app.AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),5000,pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Then receive the alarm at the **Broadcast Receiver**

```
class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // this will trigger at the alarm time

        // show notification or vibration here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the receiver in your Manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver" // need to specify the path of your receiver
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">

// this filter is optional, needed if you want to trigger the receiver even after a restart
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

This should work for all android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 won't start `Activity` from background task (alarm) if it won't have `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. try to replace `new Intent(context, MainActivity.class)` with `intent` object, which sould be declared as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

(optionally you may add also `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`)

Comment: Thanks for replying but i am having same result